# How to do tokenization to a csv file

Tags: python, spacy

I'm trying to do tokenization with spacy. I'm new to python and I want to know how to do tokenization to a csv file.

T have opened the file in Jupyter notebook:

```
    import csv
    import wheel
    
    with open('/Users/Desktop/Python Path copia/samsungs10.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
        for riga in csv_reader:
            for campo in riga:
                print(campo, end=" ")
            print("") #fine riga

    doc = nlp ('csv_file')
```

And the output is correctly the csv dataset.

Trying to tokenize I have this issue:

```
#python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

    import spacy
    import en_core_web_sm
    
    for token in doc:
        print(token.text, token.lemma_, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_,
                token.shape_, token.is_alpha, token.is_stop)
```

The output is:

```
csv_file csv_file ADP IN ROOT xxx_xxxx False False.
```

WHY?

Comment: `doc = nlp ('csv_file')` is passing a string to nlp

Comment: and how can I pass the entire file csv, ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the `nlp` object on a string of text will return a processed doc, you need to change

`doc = nlp ('csv_file')`

to the text contents of your csv reader e.g.

`doc = nlp(csv_contents)`

Edit:
In your example you have a collection of rows from a csv file. You can still use nlp to process strings row by row. Here is one way to do it:

```
import csv
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

doc = []
with open('file.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    for riga in csv_reader:
        for campo in riga:
            print(campo)
            doc.append(nlp(campo))

for item in doc:
    for token in item:
        print(token.text, token.lemma_, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_,
              token.shape_, token.is_alpha, token.is_stop)
```

Comment: Is the same: csv_reader csv_reader PROPN NNP ROOT xxx_xxxx False False

Comment: you are still passing a string with single quotations in `doc = nlp(csv_reader)`

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. Are you interested in a small project help?

Comment: @kyrion No problem. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. You can find my contact details on my profile.